# ¿Qué diferencias hay entre las apliaciones móviles Stack Exchange y Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, app-móvil

He estado viendo la posibilidad de tener en mi celular la aplicación de Stack Overflow. He buscado si existe la versión en español pero solo he encontrado estas aplicaciones para celular:

- [Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)
- [Stack Overflow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.infytechnics.stackoverflow)

No logro entender las diferencias que existen en ambas aplicaciones y si puedo ocupar alguna de estas apps para tener mi cuenta de Stack en español, que es donde participo constantemente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La aplicación móvil de Stack Exchange incluye a **todos** los sitios de preguntas y respuestas de la red, entre algunos de ellos están:

- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
- y la más importante [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Mientras que la aplicación de Stack Overflow solo incluye el sitio en inglés.

Como tú, soy usuario activo de [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), por lo que utilizo la aplicación de Stack Exchange

#### Enlaces para las aplicaciones móviles:

[Stack Overflow para iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808), [Stack Exchange para iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723)
[Stack Exchange para Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)

Es importante mencionar que actualmente [**no existe una aplicación móvil oficial de Stack Overflow para Android**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373307/4914734)